# How to un pyinstaller converted python app with Shiny for Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py-shiny

I downloaded and installed Python 3.10.6 on windows 10 pro, installed Shiny for Python, created the sample app and run it. This worked fine.

I installed pyinstaller and converted the app to an exe. I tried to run the app it threw (please see below).

Does anyone know if this can work and if so how?

This is the file2.spec that worked:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None
import os
# /c/Users/raz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/
shiny = os.path.abspath("../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/shiny")


a = Analysis(
    ['file2.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('app.py', '/'), (shiny,'/shiny')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='file2',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

This below did not work:

```
raz@rays8350 MINGW64 ~/shiny
$ cat app.py
from shiny import App, render, ui

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.h2("Hello Shiny!"),
    ui.input_slider("n", "N", 0, 100, 20),
    ui.output_text_verbatim("txt"),
)


def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render.text
    def txt():
        return f"n*2 is {input.n() * 2}"


app = App(app_ui, server)

raz@rays8350 MINGW64 ~/shiny
$


raz@rays8350 MINGW64 ~/shiny
$ ../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/shiny.exe run --reload dist/app/app.exe
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\raz\\shiny\\dist\\app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [23368] using StatReload
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subp
rocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complet
e
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 479, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 24, in import_
from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_
from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Comment: can you post the code? is it just one single file?  If not please create [example]

Comment: sure it's their demo app.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: yes, windows 10 pro

Comment: great then my answer shouldn't need any alterations all the steps I took on my windows machine.  I guess I could have figured that out from the output in your question... Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... So here are the steps I took to make it work.

1. open new directory (my_new_dir)
2. `python -m venv venv`
3. `venv\scripts\activate.bat`

   - or your OS's equivalent.
4. `pip install pyinstaller shiny`
5. open new file and paste this code in (`file1.py`)

##### file1

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.h2("Hello Shiny!"),
    ui.input_slider("n", "N", 0, 100, 20),
    ui.output_text_verbatim("txt"),
)
def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render.text
    def txt():
        return f"n*2 is {input.n() * 2}"
app = App(app_ui, server)
```

6. open a second new file next to the first (`file2.py`) and copy paste

###### file2.py

```
import os
import sys
from shiny._main import main
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
apath = os.path.join(path, "file1.py")

# these next two lines are only if you are using Windows OS
drive, apath = os.path.splitdrive(apath)
apath = apath.replace("\\","/")
# 

sys.argv = ['shiny', 'run', apath]
main()
```

7. `pyinstaller -F file2.py`

   - this will create a `file2.spec` file open it and make the changes in the code below:

file2.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
import os
                       # use OS equivalent for path below
shiny = os.path.abspath("./venv/Lib/site-packages/shiny") 

a = Analysis(
   ...
   ...
   datas = [('file1.py', '/'), (shiny,'/shiny')]  # fill in the datas value
   ...
   ...
```

Last step:

8. `pyinstaller file2.spec`

At the end of this your top level directory should look like this:

```
build
dist
venv
file1.py
file2.py
file2.spec
```

That is what worked for me. And the exe is in the `dist` folder.

If you want to change the name of the executable or the icon or any of that stuff that can all be done in the `spec` file and instructions can be found in the pyinstaller docs

Comment: How did you know to include the path to `shiny` in the datas list located in `file2.spec`?

Comment: @ChandlerTayek I tried it first without adding it and it didn't work... so I tried adding it and it did work.  And also previous experiences using pyinstaller.  I didn't even know what shiny was before reading this question.

Comment: Awgh gotcha, so with pyinstaller if there are any problems reading paths for a package you probably want to include it as a data file?

Also, I have been staring at your answer for an hour now and still can't figure out how file2.py helps kick off the shiny command.  What made you think to include `from shiny._main import main`

Comment: @ChandlerTayek  To your first question the answer is yes, it's not a guarantee but it's always worth a try.   To your second question, I went to shiny github page and looked for an easy entry point to the package in the shiny source code.

Comment: Good point! How does pyinstaller know the entry point though? It doesn't show up in the .spec file does it? I haven't tried it out but I'm assuming the file2.py puts it in some of the other parameters not listed in your answer above?

Comment: The spec file points to file2.py as the original source code that runs the exe.  So no it's not included in the spec file, but if you deleted the file2.py the spec file wouldn't work of course once you are done with the last command none of them are needed all you need is the exe @ChandlerTayek

Answer (score 1):

Adding another approach that worked for me. The previous answer only worked while the `.exe` and `app.py` files were in the same folder. (Note that there are many other reasons it may fail and lots of [good fixes](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipes) in the pyinstaller documentation).

I used `auto-py-to-exe` (a gui wrapped around pyinstaller) to add all the files used in my source code, including `app.py`. This step is analogous to editing the `datas =` section in the `.spec` file. If an error came up saying a file/folder/module was missing I added it in the gui and remade the executable.

I also had to use the `resource_path()` solution mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7675014/6595095).

For every `path` (or file) in my app, I replaced it with `resource_path(path)`. That inclues the call to start the shiny app. I told `auto-py-to-exe` to make an `.exe` file out of my "launcher" script in the same folder as `app.py`. The launcher looks like this:

```
import sys
from shiny._main import main

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

sys.argv = ['shiny', 'run', '-b', resource_path("app.py")]
main()
```

If run as an `.exe` file, `resource_path()` converts everything over to match the temporary file system defined by `pyinstaller`. If run from source files, `resource_path()` returns the original paths, making the paths safe for source and executable modes. This way the `.exe` file used the *internal* `app.py` instead of looking for the source copy. (The `-b` tells shiny to open the browser, which makes sense for my use)

Now the app will start no matter where I put the `.exe` file.